# Can I write a bullet point list in a gemspec's description and have it formatted on rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've listed the features of a gem in [my gemspec](https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus/blob/master/oedipus.gemspec), using bullet-points in a markdown style.  When pushed to rubygems.org, the description comes out on [one long line](https://rubygems.org/gems/oedipus/versions/0.0.1.pre2), without any formatting.  I then tried using HTML (`<ul>` -> `<li>`), but that just got rendered as plain text.

Is there a way to do this, or do we have to write a description that all goes on a big long line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by checking the [source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/views/rubygems/show.html.erb#L9), if the text [starts with](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/blob/master/app/helpers/rubygems_helper.rb#L12) something matching `/^==+ [A-Z]/` then it's passed through `RDoc::Markup`, which is documented [here](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html).

If you set your description to something like

```
== Description

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
```

Then it should be formatted properly on the rubygems site.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Working now. I had read the docs for the fields in the gemspec, but there is no mention of this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RubyGems docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#description) the `description` is no longer automatically formatted:

> Notes:
>
> As of Rubygems 1.3.2 there is no longer any automatic formatting of the description. Versions prior to this reformatted the description into a single line.

[RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/) doesn't offer any further information on formatting the `description` field in its [specification-reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#description).

Since RubyGems.org is the only consumer of the `description` field I'm aware of at the moment, I guess the answer is you can't. :-(

Comment: I filed [bug 40](https://github.com/rubygems/guides/issues/40) against the RubyGems.org guide. I'll update this answer as I get information about it.